# Refresh every 5 seconds - how to cache s3 files?

Tags: node.js, caching, amazon-s3

I store image files of my user model on s3. My frontend fetches new data from the backend (nodeJS) every 5 seconds. In each of those fetches, all users are retrieved which involves getting the image file from s3. Once the application scales this results in a huge request amount on s3 and high costs so I guess caching the files on the backend makes sense since they rarely change once uploaded.

How would I do it? Cache the file once downloaded from s3 onto the local file system of the server and only download them again if a new upload happened? Or is there a better mechanism for this?

Alternatively, when I set the cache header on the s3 files, are they still being fetched everytime I call `s3.getObject` or does that already achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You were right in terms of the cost, which CloudFront would not improve. I was misleading.

Back to your problem, you can cache the files in the S3 bucket adding the metadata for that. 
For example:

```
Cache-control = max-age=172800
```

You can do that in the console, or through the `aws cli` for instance.

If you request the files **directly**, and these have the headers, the browser should do a [check on the etag](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching)

> Validating cached responses with ETags TL;DR The server uses the ETag
>   HTTP header to communicate a validation token. The validation token
>   enables efficient resource update checks: no data is transferred if
>   the resource has not changed.

If you requests the files whit `s3.getObject` method it would do the request anyway, so it would download the file again.

---

## Pushing not requesting:

If you can't do this, you might want to think about the backend pushing only new data to the frontend, instead of it requesting new data every 5 seconds, which would make the load significantly lower.

### ---

### No so cost effective, more speed focused.

You could use CloudFront as a CDN for your S3 bucket. This will allow you to get the file faster, and also CloudFront would handle the cache for you.

You would need to setup the TTL accordingly to your needs, you can also invalidate the cache everytime you make an upload of a file if you need so.

[From the docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/):

> Storing your static content with S3 provides a lot of advantages. But to help optimize your application’s performance and security while effectively managing cost, we recommend that you also set up Amazon CloudFront to work with your S3 bucket to serve and protect the content. CloudFront is a content delivery network (CDN) service that delivers static and dynamic web content, video streams, and APIs around the world, securely and at scale. By design, delivering data out of CloudFront can be more cost effective than delivering it from S3 directly to your users.

Comment: This would primarily be for a boost in performance and not reduce the actual data transfer and hence the costs, right?

Comment: Possible reduced data transfer cost. As the data is not every-time transferred from same S3 bucket in a particular AWS region. So basically, if the data don't change in S3, it would always be responding the cached version (this is also relative to your TTL), thus less transfer of data.

Comment: As far as I've understood CloudFront you don't have to pay for the data transfer between s3 and CloudFront but just for the data that is being transferred between your server and CloudFront which effectively means it is the same amount as directly retrieving it from s3 as just the communication between s3 and CloudFront would be cached.

Comment: @phoebus sorry you were totally right in terms of the cost, it'd actually not improve it. I did an update whit another ideas, also could you specify why do you need to update all the user images every 5 sec? Does them change that often? If so, cache wouldnt be a valid solution either.